# Cannot get flex-end to work properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the basic bootstrap navbar markup:

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-brand-left">
        <div class="brand-img">Logo here</div>
        <div class="brand-logos">more stuff here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-brand-right">
        <div id="phone1">phone number 123</div>
        <div id="phone2">phone number 123</div>
    </div>
```

Here I want `brand-img` and `brand logos` to stay next to each other to the left, and `phone1` and `phone2` to stay next to each other to the right.
To achieve this, I apply `display:flex` to the main container `navbar`, but also to the two containers to the left and right, `navbar-brand-left` and `navbar-brand-right` so that the elements inside them can be affected as well.

What I get instead is that all the elements are spread out.

Here's the css:

```
     .navbar-header{
    display:flex; 
    align-items:center; 
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

    .navbar-brand-left{
    flex: 1;
    height:42px;
    display:flex;
    align-self:flex-start;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

    .brand-img{
    flex:1;
    }

   .brand-logos{
    flex:1; 
    margin-left:1em;
    }

    .navbar-brand-right{
    font-size:1.2em;
    height:42px;
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self:flex-end;
    }

    #phone1{
    flex:1;
    text-align:right;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    } 

    #phone2{
    flex:1;
    text-align:right;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    }
```

I've added more flex instructions than I need because I'm trying to make this work. I know in theory it should work with much less.

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et82nw0n/1/).

As you can see, **the elements don't stay at the end or at the start, but sort of tend to navigate to the middle**.

`space-between` and `flex-end` it's like they don't exist? they could be removed altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to do this:

1. Change to `justify-content: flex-start` for `navbar-brand-left`
2. Remove `flex: 1` from `brand-img`,`brand-logos`, `phone-1` and `phone-2`

See demo below:

```css
.navbar-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.navbar-brand-left {
  flex: 1;
  height: 42px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;/*CHANGED*/
  flex-direction: row;
}
.brand-img {
  /*flex: 1;*/
}
.brand-logos {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.navbar-brand-right {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 42px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
#phone1 {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#phone2 {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="navbar-brand-left">
    <div class="brand-img">Logo here</div>
    <div class="brand-logos">more stuff here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-brand-right">
    <div id="phone1">phone number 123</div>
    <div id="phone2">phone number 123</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES! thank you. It works now! I understand that those elements should not have flex:1 because this tells them to be all the same size... I always confuse those uniteless values for binary instructions that say "yes, this is flex, treat it as such" )

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-between;` to "spread" the top layer, then use traditional CSS to put the text on a single line...

https://jsfiddle.net/v4zxccvv/

```
.navbar-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.brand-img,
.brand-logos,
#phone1,
#phone2 {
  display: inline;
}
```